"A Relic from a Kinder Past..." -- what was meant?
Note: Looking up Glockenspiel it seems that is not a very good term for the Decoy Family which heroically provided refuge to the countless other Decoys.
In Mortyplicity, doubtless eons after the events involving the numerous Decoy Families, Glockenspiel Jerry (I was thinking of them as puppets/marionettes -- not sure why called that) who has been largely dismantled by beavers and probably worn by time, is discovered by what is described as dolphin/woodpecker bipedal creatures and when one asks what he is, the other says, "A relic from a kinder time." One might have thought based on that statement that they intended to help him, but the second creature begins to peck at Jerry's head.
My question is, what was meant? That in this kinder past there was the leisure to create such things or simply that wood was plentiful? Both seem plausible as the world they inhabit is quite desolate.

It's hard to rule out things based on a 10-second fragment, but it seems clear to me that by those words the dolphin-person is impliying that, while Wooden Jerry was asleep, some kind of tragedy befell Earth, which is now a wasteland populated by backward brutes, and that a large portion of human technology from their 21st century is lost to time.
Since you seem to be interested in the dichotomy "technology is lost versus wood is lost", it should be pointed out that the woodpecker-person is the one asking what Jerry is, and the dolphin-person is the one referring to the relic from a kinder past. The other way around would make more sense if they were meant to talk about wood.

The "backwards brutes" are the two creatures who discover Jerry?

@releseabe Possibly, but certainly not limited to them.
